# Rename the dataLayer parameter for the new gtag.js?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the new gtag.js on a website with existing Google Tag Manager dataLayer. I am trying to send events via gtag but because GTM also uses the same window.dataLayer for its operation (and we have some custom operation going on the dataLayer, so I cannot change over there), events are not being sent.

Is there a way to rename window.dataLayer for gtag.js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would seem so. Since gtag uses infrastructure from GTM I look how GTM goes about renaming the dataLayer and tried the same with gtag:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123456789-1&l=foo"></script>
<script>
  window.foo = window.foo || [];
  function gtag(){foo.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-1');
</script>
```

Watching the console in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umvdthdx/2/) I could see that the pageview was sent. adding the "l" query parameter with your desired datalayer name to the script tag seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I did try this method before, as I know GTM allows dataLayer renaming. However, this was not working for me before. However, I will try to see with "l" parameter. Maybe that was what was needed.

Comment: Since this came up high on Google for me, here is a link to the documentation on how to do this:
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/datalayer#rename_the_data_layer